# Sort data according to selected field from dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a project using angularjs. In my project i want to sort the data according to selected field from dropdown.

```
Here is Fiddle:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/32479/

Please help

Comment: please have a look here: [mcve] and add all relevant information to the question.

Comment: You can start by checking [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) .

Comment: KarelG, angular have buildin filters  to dynamicly order or filter displayed array (with ng-repeat) without order the array itself each time

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the official doc or make a search on google can answer 99% of your need

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

```
<div ng-repeat="x in data |orderBy: selectedValue">
    <div>{{x.name}}</div>
    <div>{{x.account}}</div>
    <div>{{x.cloud}} </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using orderBy

```
<div ng-repeat="x in data  | orderBy:propertyName">
    <div>{{x.name}}</div>
    <div>{{x.account}}</div>
    <div>{{x.cloud}} </div>
</div>
```